# R - Obtain Column Names for Each Dataframe in a List based on a Parameter

Tags: r, list, names

I have a list of dataframes that I have divided in order to do individual statistics on. The dataframes have names to columns that I want to extract based on a value in a row. Take these dataframes for example compiled in `df_list`:

```
$df1
  aa bb cc
a  9  9  2
b  9  9  6
c  2 10  5
d  2  9  6
e  3  4  7

$df2
  aa bb cc
a  2  4  3
b  2  8  2
c  6  4  3
d  9  5  8
e  1  5  4

$df3
  aa bb cc
a  1  8  2
b  1  8  9
c  4  1  2
d  9  9  8
e  9  7  3
```

I wanted to obtain the names  of columns if row e is greater than 5. So I would get an output something like this either in the same list or a brand new list:

```
$df1
  [1] "cc" 

$df2
  NULL  #or integer(0), I'm not quite sure what I would see here

$df3
  [1] "aa"    "bb"
```

I've come up with this code to get the names of all columns:

```
names_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) colnames(x))

$df1
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"

$df2
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"

$df3
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"
```

And this is the line of code for columns greater than 5:

```
num_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) which(x[c("e"),] > 5))

$df1
[1] 3

$df2
integer(0)

$df3
[1] 1 2
```

While the last two results are promising, I can't seem to connect the two ideas together to get the desired output. Nesting them gives me countless errors I can't identify. Is there a feasible way to do this? Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subset the `names` of the dataframe :

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) names(x)[x['e', ] > 5])
#Similar to OP's attempt. 
#lapply(df_list, function(x) names(x)[which(x[c("e"),] > 5)])

#$df1
#[1] "cc"

#$df2
#character(0)

#$df3
#[1] "aa" "bb"
```

**data**

```
df_list <- list(df1 = structure(list(aa = c(9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 3L), bb = c(9L, 
9L, 10L, 9L, 4L), cc = c(2L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")), 
df2 = structure(list(aa = c(2L, 2L, 6L, 
9L, 1L), bb = c(4L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 5L), cc = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 4L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
)), df3 = structure(list(aa = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 9L), bb = c(8L, 
8L, 1L, 9L, 7L), cc = c(2L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")))
```

Comment: Its Interesting that `[x['e', ] > 5]` was all that was needed to fix this. I found that `colnames` gives the same output as `names` argument, but its great to know the functionality of names for future use. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
 map(df_list, ~  .x %>% 
         rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
         filter(rn == 'e') %>% 
         pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% 
         filter(value > 5) %>%
         pull(name))
#$df1
#[1] "cc"

#$df2
#character(0)

#$df3
#[1] "aa" "bb"
```

#### data

```
df_list <- list(df1 = structure(list(aa = c(9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 3L), bb = c(9L, 
9L, 10L, 9L, 4L), cc = c(2L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")), 
df2 = structure(list(aa = c(2L, 2L, 6L, 
9L, 1L), bb = c(4L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 5L), cc = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 4L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
)), df3 = structure(list(aa = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 9L, 9L), bb = c(8L, 
8L, 1L, 9L, 7L), cc = c(2L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")))
```

Comment: This seems very useful! I will investigate into this. Thank you!